# What is the difference of Orchard CMS Input field vs Text field?

Tags: orchardcms

Would you help me to understand what's the difference of this two fields in Orchard CMS?

Many thanks,

Rocky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The InputField is newer than the TextField and has more options, such as the ability to set the type (e.g. text, tel, email), autofocus, autocomplete, placeholder text, editor css class and maxlength.

The TextField on the other hand supports a flavor, allowing you to turn the text field into a single line textbox, a textarea, a markdown editor, html editor, or any other flavor provided by any module.

In my opinion, we should consider getting rid of the Input Field and update the TextField in core with the capabilities found in InputField. This avoids confusion and at the same time offers greater flexibility.